# Naming example for actionAjaxDie<ControllerName><Method>Before hook in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Reading [Prestashop hooks doc](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.7.x), I have not found in the doc, or with a search engine, an example on how to implement the hook `actionAjaxDie<ControllerName><Method>Before`.

Here is my case:

I want to implement `actionAjaxDie<ControllerName><Method>Before` hook on method `displayAjaxRefresh()` of class `CartControllers` from `[Prestashop Project]/controllers/front/CartControllers.php`.

In the `install()` method of my custom module: `[Prestashop Project]/modules/mymodule/mymodule.php`.

It is not clear if I should implement `actionAjaxDie<ControllerName><Method>Before` with an **uppercase letter** on the name of the method **or a lowercase** or another way that I haven't foreseen:

`$this->registerHook('actionAjaxDieCartControllerDisplayAjaxRefreshBefore')`

**or**

`$this->registerHook('actionAjaxDieCartControllerdisplayAjaxRefreshBefore')`

**or** some other pattern?

Answer (score 0):

After test it works with the uppercase letter on the first letter of the method:

`$this->registerHook('actionAjaxDieCartControllerDisplayAjaxRefreshBefore')`

and in `[Prestashop Project]/modules/mymodule/mymodule.php` it calls method :

`actionAjaxDieCartControllerDisplayAjaxRefreshBefore()`.